# How to calculate relative positions in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to handle the position of a particular View, during a DragGesture. I want that my app reacts to the position of this View. As showed in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFLhJ.gif),  I want that the black circles become red when the black one is over them. I think I might use a GeometryReader, but I don't understand how it works. Thanks to all!

Comment: please read and consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and show us, what you tried so far. This is not a "we code for you for free"-platform, but a "we help you with your existing code you tried so far" - platform

Comment: You're right Chris. Next time I will follow the guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. We must use GeometryReader to detect the position of view. Here is a sample code. I hope it will help you.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var position: CGPoint = .zero
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { _ in
                    CircleView(position: self.$position)
                }
            }.padding()
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .position(self.position)
                .onAppear {
                    self.position = CGPoint(x: proxy.frame(in: .global).midX, y: proxy.frame(in: .global).midY + 100)
                }
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                        self.position = value.location
                    }.onEnded { value in
                        self.position = value.location
                    }
                )
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
}

struct CircleView: View {
@Binding var position: CGPoint
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(self.color(frame: proxy.frame(in: .global)))
    }
    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    .animation(.easeIn)
}
func color(frame: CGRect) -> Color {
    if
        position.x >= frame.minX && position.x <= frame.maxX
        &&
        position.y >= frame.minY && position.y <=  frame.maxY
    {
        return .red
    }
    return .black
}
}
```

Thanks. X_X